# Is it recommended to disable CSS to check a website for accessibility?

Tags: css, accessibility, wcag, wcag2.0

Many developers/accessibility experts suggest to disable CSS for checking the website for accessibility, but no one explicitly says how it may actually be helpful in terms of web accessibility.

So here I am, asking you exactly that, because all my attempts to check this in reliable (I WANT TO BELIEVE!) sources like "w3.org", including their WCAG 2.0 recommendations, don't say anything about making website accessible without CSS. Moreover, they say it may be "relied upon" some technology, like CSS, for example.

Answer (score 3):

You no longer need to explicitly verify that pages are readable without CSS, but it can be useful as a technique for ensuring correct reading order.

The requirement to make pages readable without CSS is a carryover from the days when Section 508 was the dominant accessibility standard.

> 36 CFR Parts 1193 and 1194 - Published February 18, 2017
>
> *There is no direct analogy in the WCAG 2.0 Success Criteria for section 1194.22(d) of the existing 508 Standards, which states: “documents shall be organized so they are readable without requiring an associated style sheet.” 36 CFR §1194.22(d)*.
>
> https://www.access-board.gov/guidelines-and-standards/communications-and-it/about-the-ict-refresh/final-rule/single-file-version

WCAG 2.0 addresses this same issue in a different way with [Success Criterion 1.3.2 - Meaningful Sequence](https://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/content-structure-separation-sequence.html).

One of the techniques for meeting this criterion is [making the DOM order match the visual order (C27)](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/NOTE-WCAG20-TECHS-20161007/C27), which is largely what this comes down to anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that a good reason to actually disable CSS in terms of checking accessibility is to see that your site structure is built up in a logical way.

On the other hand, **a better way to test this is to use a screenreader** and tab through the site using use *tab* / *shift + tab* with a keyboard. In that way you do not only get an eureka-moment on structural issues you also get the audio-feedback that will give you lots of AHA:s about phrasing, ARIA-issues and hidden elements not hidden in a accessible way.

I'd point you to try out [ChromeVox](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chromevox/kgejglhpjiefppelpmljglcjbhoiplfn)

Comment: You're right, disabling CSS is a good way to test structure and order of element, but can you elaborate about "you also get the audio-feedback that will give you lots of AHA:s about phrasing, ARIA-issues and hidden elements not hidden in a accessible way"? Would be awesome to see any examples if possible too. Thanks for helping, pal.

Comment: One basic example is when you think you have done a great "open menu button". You set aria-label to "Open menu" (or any other accessibility text) and do the script changes when clicking so it says Close.

All looks nice and dandy, but when you use the ChromeVox and only use keyboard to tab your way to the element you never get there. I've found problems like that because I (or someone else) forgot to make the button a semantic correct button!
Examples are hard, but I overdid a searchfield updating the search button with text input. Tested by a blind person said, nice done but confusing. =)

Answer (score 0):

If you use the accessibility testing tool [Wave](http://wave.webaim.org/extension/) you can actually disable styles in the tool. So, as built in a testing tool it's a great way to test the structural element flow. There is no purpose in itself to disable CSS besides testing accessibility in this way.